# WinHttpReceiveResponse() always returns ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE

Tags: winapi, iis-7, winhttp, smooth-streaming

I'm trying to add WinHTTP authentication to my application. The application should connect to the IIS and stream some data. After sending some chunked data with the `WinHttpWriteData()` API (Transfer-Encoding: Chunked), I can see in network monitor that IIS responded with 401 (unauthorized). However, if I call `WinHttpReceiveResponse()` in order to retrieve that response, that API always fails with `ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_HANDLE_STATE`. The documentation doesn't define the "state", so it is pretty much meaningless to me. I should also mention that I can talk to IIS with no problems if I create an authorization rule for all users without any authentication.
Also, none of the examples provided in the MSDN regarding WinHTTP authentication are functional when I try them on my IIS.

working example with no authorization:

```
// Send the chunk size
WinHttpWriteData( httpPostRequest, httpChunkData, (DWORD)strlen( httpChunkData ), &dwWritten );
// Send the data
WinHttpWriteData( httpPostRequest, pData, size, &dwWritten );
// Send the end
WinHttpWriteData( httpPostRequest, "\r\n", 2, &dwWritten );
```

The 401 arrives after the last `WinHttpWriteData()`, but I cannot get it with `WinHttpReceiveResponse()`.
If anybody could provide just a few lines of pseudo code on how to do it, I would appreciate it very much.

EDIT:
I'm using WinHTTP in synchronous mode.

EDIT #2:
The above description was related to basic authentication. I disabled it and enabled windows authentication. I have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383144(v=vs.85).aspx more than once and the result is:

```
WinHttpSendRequest() - SUCCESS
WinHttpReceiveResponse() - SUCCESS
WinHttpQueryHeaders() - SUCCESS, status code = 401
WinHttpQueryAuthSchemes() - SUCCESS, auth scheme = WINHTTP_AUTH_SCHEME_NEGOTIATE
WinHttpSetCredentials() - SUCCESS

now I repeat the first two calls:
WinHttpSendRequest() - SUCCESS
WinHttpReceiveResponse() - FAILURE with code ERROR_WINHTTP_CONNECTION_ERROR
```

It seems that log on IIS shows that username/password is not correct. I even tried to log as admin, but it doesn't work either. Unfortunately, something very important is missing in bad MS documentation.

**EDIT #3**
Found the problem!

```
WinHttpSendRequest( hPostRequest,
                    L"Transfer-Encoding: Chunked\r\n",
                    (DWORD)-1,
                    WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA,
                    0,
                    WINHTTP_IGNORE_REQUEST_TOTAL_LENGTH,
                    0 );
```

If I remove the additional headers (Transfer-Encoding: Chunked), then it works, but I need that chunked encoding. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: What are the three `WinHttpWriteData` calls returning?

Comment: @Jonathan, they all return TRUE

Comment: And you're not doing this asynchronously?

Comment: @Jonathan, no, I'm doing it synchronously.

Comment: The error you're getting simply means the request handle isn't in the right "state" for the call, e.g. it's not in a state to service a read request because the headers are still being received. I don't know why it would be failing and not blocking until it is ready, however.

Comment: @Jonathan, does switching to async mode makes any sense? I mean, can I expect different behaviour for any reason in that case?

Comment: I don't know that it would help, it just would have provided a more likely reason for the problem. You could have a play around with `WinHttpSetStatusCallback` - see if you actually get notified that the headers are available, and if so try reading the state once they are.

Comment: What authentication method are you using? If your server uses basic authentication, you can pre-authenticate the request by sending the user name and password on the initial request, otherwise the rest of the authentication methods require more back and forth communication between server and client to authenticate.

Comment: @NathanMoinvaziri, first I tried the basic authentication and I got the behaviour I described. Then I disabled it and I enabled windows authentication. I will edit the question and  describe the problem.